# Upgrading to 15.04 stalls when trying to install MySQL 5.6

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, mysql

I've just tried to upgrade my ubuntu OS (desktop) and it's just stopped when installing MySQL. It said that i had to update the password (did this twice in the install) but the second time it said "cannot save password" then stalled and froze.

I now have a half installed new OS and i'm worried that if i stop the installer, restart my machine, or try and downgrade back to 14.XX then my machine will be broken.

I think the issue is very similar to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.6/+bug/1435080

but i dont know how to fix this when it's half way through the install.

This is the normal ubuntu software update centre (Vivid or something)

To recap:

If an install crashes, can i start the install again or will it mess everything up?

Comment: I had the same problem.  Still looking for a solution.

Comment: I never found a solution, i stopped the update and have reverted back to the older version of the OS. Such a pain in the neck.